# What does this expressionengine template code mean?

Tags: expressionengine

```
    {if exclude-locales}
        {exp:cookie_plus:get name="cklocale" parse="inward"}
            {exclude-locales}
                {if "{option_name}" != "{cookie}"}
                    <p>
   content goes here
                    </p>
                {/if} 
            {/exclude-locales}
        {/exp:cookie_plus:get}
   {if:else}...
```

I've been told that 'exclude-locales' is the name of a custom field. I'm looking to understand what the condition {if exclude-locales} actually means and also what 'parse="inward"' does?

exclude-locales is a gypsy field of type FF Multi Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what the condition {if exclude-locales} actually means

exclude-locales must be a boolean/bool type of data type.

{if exclude-locales} means if the value of "exclude-locales" is true, then go inside the if part of the loop i.e. execute

> {exp:cookie_plus:get name="cklocale" parse="inward"}

code.

Comment: Actually. exclude-locales is a field of type FF Multi-select. SO what would if do then? And what is parse=inward doing?

Comment: I think that parse=inward means evaluate the outer plugin first

Comment: @codecowboy is right. If there are plugins within plugins in an EE template, they're normally parsed from inner to outer plugin. The `parse="inward"` parameter reverses this behavior so that the outer-most plugin tag parses first. See: http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order